# poisson integral formula unit ball

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, spheres

Let $u: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, $u \in C^2$ be a solution to $\Delta u = 0$ in $B_1(0)$. Moreover $u(x) = \alpha x_1^2$ on the boundary $\partial B_1(0)$.

(i) Calculate $\alpha$ under the condition that $u(0)=1$.

(ii) Calculate $\nabla u(0)$.

I know that I have to use the Poisson integral formula, which is given by
Let $u \in C^2\overline{(B_R(0))}$ be a harmonic function. Than
$u(x) = \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{R S_n} \int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{u(y)}{|x-y|^n} ds$, $~~~$ $x \in B_R(0)$.

But if I try to set it up for my problem, I end up with a division by zero since $|x-y|^n$=$|0-0|^2$. I'm sure I mistake y here for something it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Poisson integral formula, we get that
\begin{align}
u(0) =&\ \frac{R}{2\pi} \int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{u(y)}{|y|^2}\ dS = \frac{1}{2R} \int_{\partial B_R(0)} u(y)\ dS\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2} \int^{2\pi}_0 u(R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta)\ d\theta = \frac{\alpha }{2} \int^{2\pi}_0 R^2\cos^2\theta\ d\theta = \frac{\alpha \pi R^2}{2}=1
\end{align}
which means $\alpha = 2/\pi R^2$.

Next, observe
\begin{align}
\nabla u(x) =&\ \frac{-x}{\pi R}\int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{u(y)}{|x-y|^2}\ dS + \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{2\pi R}\int_{\partial B_R(0)} u(y) \nabla_x\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}\right)\ dS\\
=&\ \frac{-x}{\pi R}\int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{u(y)}{|x-y|^2}-\frac{R^2-|x|^2}{2\pi R}\int_{\partial B_R(0)} u(y)\frac{(x-y)}{|x-y|^4}\ dS
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\partial_1 u(0) =&\ \frac{R}{2\pi}\int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{u(y)}{|y|^4} y_1\ dS = \frac{1}{2\pi R^3} \int_{\partial B_R(0)} u(y) y_1\ dS\\
 =&\ \frac{\alpha}{2\pi R} \int^{2\pi}_0 u(R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta)\cos\theta\ d\theta = \frac{\alpha R}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 \cos^3\theta\ d\theta =0 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\partial_2 u(0) = \frac{\alpha R}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 \cos^2\theta \sin\theta\ d\theta=0.\ 
\end{align}